# .Map function difference javascript typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im changing javascript code to typescript in an application and note the following problem:

Working javascript code:

```
var x= $.makeArray($(comparisonObjects)
            .map(function (i, o) {
            if (o.Id !== IdtoRemove) {
                return o;
            }
            return null;
        }));
```

This does not work in typescript because "o" is asserted to be an object of "Element" type, even though it is actually an object which contains an Id.

Note that I DO NOT wish to access an elements' id property. ComparisonObjects is already an array of business objects which have their own Id property.

So the actual problem is that Im being forced to treat my object as an Element, not allowing me to access the object.

What would be the correct way to deal with this in typescript?

Comment: Note that the `.map()` in use here is the jQuery `.map()`, not the native `Array.prototype.map()`. (At least, that's my guess from the `$()` use.)

Comment: And if that *is* jQuery, then it would be `o.id` not `o.Id`. The second argument is (probably) a DOM element, and the property name is lower-case "id".

Comment: I agree, I was currently browsing jquery's doc to check that. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/map/)'s the relevant page, which denotes that the second parameter to the callback function is an `Element`

Comment: @Pointy: I added explanation, I hope you understand what I mean now. I do not want an elements' id property. Rather I want to access my own created business objects' Id property.

Comment: What  is the value of `comparisonObjects`? Are those in fact jQuery calls? If so, why, if you're not working with DOM elements?

Comment: You are entirely correct. I did not read well enough. The only thing I did wrong was casting it to a Jquery object for no reason and I did not even realize it -_-.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with plain arrays, you don't need to make jQuery objects:

```
var x = comparisonObjects.filter(function(object) {
  return object.Id !== IdToRemove;
});
```

That'll give you a new array containing only objects that satisfy your condition. The native `.map()` function for arrays does not pay attention to return values like the jQuery `.map()` does.